# How can I get/identify feature titles/names in REST?

Tags: rest, feature, feature-activation

SharePoint 2013

I'm able to view all site collection active features via the following endpoint `_api/site/features`.

I'm unable to match any of the guids to feature titles; the endpoint doesn't seem to have pass along display names (I've tried including `?$select=DisplayName`).

Is there any way to identify all or individual feature names? My intent is to build a REST call to activate 2 specific features on a site.

Comment: I have 18 active features on the site collection, and 51 listed on the gui. I have 71 features listed using `/_api/features`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to match up the features by identifying the div ID in the Site features page `_layouts/15/ManageFeatures.aspx?Scope=Site`.

Only active features show up in `_api/site/features`. Any extras might be dependencies which won't necessarily be named on the features page.